# How to buy Destiny: The Taken King with both expansions and no base game?

Tags: destiny

I have decided that I would like to buy The Taken King for Destiny, but I only own the base game so far, and neither of the previous expansions. It seems to me that the only ways to buy The Taken King are either the base game and all three expansions or just TTK. Since the first two expansions are required for TTK, the second option obviously doesn't work, but the first way I am buying an extra copy of Destiny that I don't need, which I guess would be okay, except then what would happen to my original copy? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'ts not possible to do so. it's just how Activision/Bungie forces you to buy everything again.

Comment: The Legendary Edition (which has the base game, both expansions, and TTK) costs $60. Buying the DLC only costs $75 (Expansion Pass is $35, TTK is $40). So even though you are re-buying the base game, you're saving money.

Comment: @Adeese But then I will have two copies of Destiny. What will happen to the other one? Will I still keep my progress?

Comment: @ArtiSchmidt Your characters are stored on Bungie's servers, so you won't lose any progress. If you bought on disc, the new disc is identical to the old one. If digital, then (I think, could depend on your console) you will have 2 copies on your account.

Comment: @Robotnik Valve/Steam has nothing to do with any of this since Destiny ain't on PC.

Comment: @BadAtPHP - touche. I read it wrong, thought it was something else

Comment: Of note that if your original was on disc and you buy the new one digitally then you will then no longer need your disc and presumably would be able to trade it in somewhere as second hand. I actually bought the full digital bundle purely as the only way to get a digital version of the base game now. :)